# How to solve error when creating a new NX Workspace?

Tags: npm, cmd, repository, monorepo, npx

For my new projects I want to create a monorepo with NX. Therefor I used the command `npx create-nx-workspace` in the cmd on Windows 10 in the directory where I want to create it. But it stops and throws an error with no message. Any Idea?

Cmd:

```
C:\Users\aerith\Desktop\Repository\test-repo>npx create-nx-workspace

 >  NX   Let's create a new workspace [https://nx.dev/getting-started/intro]

√ Choose what to create                 · package-based
√ Repository name                       · test-repo
√ Enable distributed caching to make your CI faster · Yes

 >  NX   Nx is creating your v15.8.3 workspace.

   To make sure the command works reliably in all environments, and that the preset is applied correctly,
   Nx will run "npm install" several times. Please wait.

√ Installing dependencies with npm
× Creating your workspace in test-repo

 >  NX   Nx failed to create a workspace.

   Error:


C:\Users\aerith\Desktop\Repository\test-repo>
```